# MiniTest parent and child from factory in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, minitest

I'm getting the following error when running my test.
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'departure_date' for nil:NilClass`

Here is the test.

```
  test "successful disbursement should respond with success" do

    post :disbursement, {id: @invoice.invoice_id, trip: attributes_for(:trip)}
    assert_response :success
  end
```

In the setup portion of the test I'm creating the following.

```
  setup do
    @controller = Api::V1::InvoicesController.new
    @invoice = create(:invoice)
    @trip = create(:trip)
  end
```

The **trip** factory looks like this.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :trip do
    depart_airport "MCI"
    arrive_airport "ORD"
    passenger_first_name "Joe"
    passenger_last_name "Business"
    passenger_count 1
    departure_date {10.days.from_now}
    invoice
  end

end
```

The **invoice** factory looks like this.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    sequence(:invoice_id) { |n| "INV#{n}"}
    merchant
    amount 500.00
    item_count 5
    paid false
    currency "GBP"
    invoice_type "pre-flight"
  end

end
```

Can't quite figure out how to make sure the invoice has a trip. I'm guessing this is why the test can't find the departure_date it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to associate the trip and invoice. If my understanding is correct, try this.

```
setup do
    @controller = Api::V1::InvoicesController.new
    @invoice = create(:invoice)
    @trip = create(:trip, invoice: @invoice)
  end
```